# what is [ -f /home/aaa.sh ] in bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm wondering the meaning of the following two lines in a bash script
[ ... ] is for conditional statement.

What is `-f filename` inside?

```
[ -f /home/aaa.sh ] || cp ../home/dir1/aaa.sh bin/

[ ! -f /home/bbb.sh ] || cp ../home/dir2/bbb.sh bin/
```

Comment: This is hard to find using search engines; I suggest you try `man test` or http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html (look for `-f`)

Comment: Paste this command on [explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=%5B+-f+%2Fhome%2Faaa.sh+%5D+%7C%7C+cp+..%2Fhome%2Fdir1%2Faaa.sh+bin%2F) for a detailed breakdown

Comment: Have you read [a Bash manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)?

Comment: This is not directly relevant to the question, but it seems odd to have an executable script directly under the `/home` directory. Normally `/home` contains only users' home directories.